# Kindly suggest solved and unsolved question bank on Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am having difficulty understanding the physics where force and motion(both translation and rotation)  is considered.

I am unable to visualise and develop an understanding when it comes to motions of connected links , blocks , springs,damper or real life scenarios.

Please suggest a book which dives into lots of questions covering different scenarios which starts with simple question and  then slowly go on increasing the complexity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/168783)

Comment: (while the post I linked doesn't consider the exact same question, this question seems to be considerably wide for a single resource recommendation post, and I believe it is already addressed in the links mentioned in the post I tagged)

Comment: The Schaum Outline series of books has always been a favorite of mine for this sort of purpose.  They're fairly common so check in libraries as well to see if you can borrow them.

Comment: Shankar. Fundamentals of Physics. Volume 1. (Volume 2 is good too but it covers electricity, thermo, and quantum) There are videos on youtube but the books are worth having. He's a absolute master at teaching physics concepts.

Comment: Is there any book which covers lots of questions only(related to Newton's laws of motion and it's application)

Answer (score 2):

If you need some general physics textbook recommendation, I'd take a look at these introductory collections (Halliday & Resnick, Serway etc.). I particularly like Randall Knight's Physics, a Strategic Approach. I assume you've taken classes/self-studied differential and integral calculus and some vectory algebra and geometry.

After the first volume of Mechanics you could probably tackle Kleppner and Kolenkow's Mechanics which is very, very nice and has some good problems to get you thinking and really test your understanding.

Comment: Is there any book which covers lots of questions only(related to Newton's laws of motion and it's application)